# 4th column is not getting inserted in sqlite table?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sql-insert

I have already added 3 columns in SQLite table and it works fine. but when I add the fourth column it does not work. I guess it might be an issue with the query.

```
private  static String key_id="id";
private  static String key_name="name";
private  static String key_email="email";
private  static String key_phone="phone";
private  static String key_table="user_table";

      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


     /**please add the fourth column which will be key_mobile I already 
     tried but still not working****/ 

     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + key_table + " (" + key_id + " INTEGER 
     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + key_name + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
     key_email + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + key_phone + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
     }

     public long insertCustomer(Customer customer)
     {
      SQLiteDatabase sqlite= this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(key_id,customer.getId());
      values.put(key_name,customer.getName());
      values.put(key_email,customer.getEmail());
      values.put(key_phone,customer.getPhone());
      long row = sqlite.insert(key_table,null,values);
      sqlite.close();
      return row;
     }
```

When I remove ( key_phone + " TEXT NOT NULL ), it works but, I need the fourth column. The insert method returns -1 instead of current row id.

Comment: Uninstall the app from the device so the database is deleted and rerun to recreate.

Comment: I have already deleted database file using andriod studio

Comment: Remove the line `values.put(key_id,customer.getId());` let SQLite generate the id. You may be using the same id (UNIQUE constraint conflict). If that doesn't fix it then it may be that **customer.getPhone()** is getting a null (NOT NULL constraint conflict). If you change (temporarily) `long row = sqlite.insert(key_table,null,values);` to `long row = sqlite.insertOrThrow(key_table,null,values);` then an exception will allow you to see what cause the -1 (insert effectively uses INSERT OR IGNORE so ignores some constraint conflicts, such as not null and unique (both potential issues as above)).

Comment: The id is not the issue. It works if I put three columns(id,name,email).

Comment: I am using andriod device. I have replace the insert() method with insertorthrow(). I run the app it says application stopped working....

Comment: It works. I just uninstall the app. Thanks for your help.